# SQL Server 2008: why doesn't BETWEEN handle strings which include the dash (-)?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, between

My applications pulls rows from a table which contain a column = StringA. The user enters 2 parameters, From and Thru strings, and if she enters the same string in both, and the string has an embedded dash, it's not working.

Why doesn't the following return True where ColumnA and StringA = 'medi-care', but it does return true where ColumnA and StringA = 'medicare' (no dash)?

```
IF ColumnA between StringA and StringA...
```

I also tried:

```
IF ColumnA <= StringA and ColumnA >= StringA...
```

Is this a bug? I tried appending a 'z' to the `Thru` parameter string - still didn't work for the string with a dash embedded. Can you suggest a way to make this work?

Comment: Not clear at all.  Post sample data.  If StringA='medicare' returns true then  StringA='medicare'.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you actually have an en dash or em dash in one of them but not the other.  Often times it is very difficult to tell.  Ex:

```
Declare @StringA varchar(20)
Declare @ColumnA VarChar(20)

Select @StringA = 'medi-care',
        @ColumnA = 'medi—care'

Select 'They Match'
Where  @StringA = @ColumnA
```

Note that in this example, @ColumnA actually has an en dash instead of a dash.  If you look closely, you may be able to tell, but it is very difficult to notice a difference unless you are specifically looking for it.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.   I ran this on SQL 2008R2:

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE (
  ColA varchar(7)
);

INSERT INTO @Test (ColA) VALUES ('a-z');

SELECT * FROM @Test WHERE ColA BETWEEN 'a-z' AND 'a-z';
```

And I got the result of 'a-z'.   There must be something else in your data that is causing the non-match.   Blank spaces or other invisible characters.